# What does "Hate emanates from within, love without" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, quotations

> Hate emanates from within, love without

I read this on a website but couldn't quite understand what it meant, and so if possible, can someone tell me its meaning, it would be great.

Comment: Can you please link to the website? I did a search for this text and I can't find it.  I'd like to see it in context.  Have you checked the meaning of the "hard" word *emanate*?

Comment: You say you "couldn't quite understand".  So you understand a little bit? Can you say what you do understand?

Comment: Are you aware that, as well as the everyday meaning of _without_ "lacking", there is an older and now rather literary meaning of "outside", which contrasts with "within"? Does that make the sentence clearer?

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense. *emanates from without*? Comes from the outside to inside something? That's not *emanation*.

Comment: Hate emanates from within, love [emanates] from without. emanate=to come from. without=the outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clarify a couple of definitions:

> **emanate**, v. to come … from a source

> **without**, adv. outside

*(Source: OED)*

Knowing those, the sentence makes a little more sense:

> Hate comes from within [a person], love [comes from] outside.

I'm not sure that as a sentence it makes a great deal of sense, as you could argue the opposite is true. But that's beyond the scope of learning the sentence's meaning!

Comment: "Aspirational quotes" have been getting steadily worse since "Hang in there" first gave us the cat on a washing line. People usually try to add weight to their wooly thinking by accrediting it to the Dali Lama or Lincoln. ;)

Comment: understood, thank you Dan, and yes I think so too that the sentence is extremely debatable